# Not getting data in Angular while passing in router using navigation extras

Tags: angular, routes, angular11

I am using angular 11
in one component I have written this

```
user = {
id:1 ,
name:'abc'
}
constructor(private router2:Router) {
    super(inj);
    
        this.router2.navigateByUrl('/register',{ state: {user: this.user} });
   
  }
```

in register component I have written this

```
constructor(private router2: Router) {
    
    console.log('data',this.router2.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state )
   
  }
```

in console it is showing undefined in data
can anyone have idea about it why it is happening

Comment: You should use navigate instead of navigateByUrl

Comment: @FatihErsoy if I use navigate still not getting the data

Comment: I added solution, you should be able to reach it. If not, can you please provide a simple stackblitz example?

Comment: @FatihErsoy your solution is also not working it is still giving me undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to send data, I would recommend data instead of that.

```
this.router.navigate([path], { data: {something: 111} });
```

And your component could be

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  console.log(route.snapshot.data);
}
```

Comment: this won't work I guess because data is not a part of NavigationExtras so this will not work

Answer (score 0):

Try that one within your constructor (capturing navigation events can be necessary). If you navigate back from a child component, wait until the navigation process is finished and check afterwards, if there is a state:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    const routeData = this.router?.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras;
    const state = routeData?.state;

    if (state) {
      // Do whatever you want to with it
    } else {
      // No state is transferred
    }
  }
});
```

**You have to import:**

```
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
```

**Your constructor:**

```
constructor (
// ...
private router: Router
) {
// ...
}
```